# Why does my lawnmower air filter have a metal wire mesh?

Tags: small-engine, air-filter

I bought two spare paper air filters for my lawnmower. Once they arrived, I noticed an interesting feature in them. The side of the air filter that is at the carburetor/engine side has a thick metal wire mesh.

What is the purpose of this wire mesh?

Is it somehow trying to protect intake backfire from igniting the paper in the air filter by dissipating heat? Or is it there just in case some large object would puncture the paper air filter and travel inside the engine with the airstream?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The purpose of it is to support the paper element. If the paper element were to get wet or get too much junk in it, it would run the risk of getting sucked into the engine, which might cause damage ... at the very least would cause you a bad day.